# Volume of solid inside a paraboloid and an elliptic paraboloid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm preparing for a calculus exam and came across this problem. I've looked around for similar problems that have been posted here, but the ones I've found don't seem to present this particular difficulty. Here's the problem:

Find the volume bounded by the surfaces $z = x^2+y^2$ and $z=10-x^2-2y^2$.

I thought I could just find the intersection, and then divide the triple integral in two parts, one above the intersection and the other below. The thing is, the intersection of these surfaces is not contained in any plane $z = z_0$, so I'm lost here. Any help finding the limits of integration would be appreciated.

Here's a picture (not the best, sorry) of these surfaces and their intersection:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQc81.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume is limited by the two surfaces so that:
$$
x^2+y^2\le z \le 10-x^2-2y^2
$$
are the limits for $z$.

From: $x^2+y^2 \le 10-x^2-2y^2$  we find:
$$
-\sqrt{\frac{10-2x^2}{3}}\le y \le \sqrt{\frac{10-2x^2}{3}}
$$
that are the limits for $y$, and these are real numbers iff
$$
-\sqrt{5} \le x \le \sqrt{5}
$$
that are the limits for $x$.

So the volume is
$$
V=\int_{-\sqrt{5}}^{\sqrt{5}}\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{10-2x^2}{3}}}^{\sqrt{\frac{10-2x^2}{3}}}
\int_{x^2+y^2}^{10-x^2-2y^2}dzdydx
$$